# MySQL import csv only gets half the lines

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I use the following command to read in a csv:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/Tyler/Desktop/players_escaped.txt' 
INTO TABLE players
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '^'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The csv looks like this:

```
^1^,^False^,^False^,^Ovie^,^Soko^,^6^,^8^,^210^,^^,^M^,^London^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^0^,^2009^,^^,^False^,^False^,^{299F909C-88D9-4D26-8ADC-3EC1A66168BB}^,^844^,^2013^,^^,^^,^0^,^^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^1^,^2^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^
^2^,^False^,^False^,^Jordan^,^Swing^,^6^,^6^,^200^,^^,^M^,^Birmingham^,^AL^,^35218^,^^,^^,^0^,^2009^,^^,^False^,^False^,^{299F909C-88D9-4D26-8ADC-3EC1A66168BB}^,^844^,^2013^,^^,^^,^0^,^^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^2011-02-16 20:53:34.877000000^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^1^,^2^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^,^^
```

I also tried `\` as a delimiter and got the same results.

I'm only getting the odd numbered rows.

There are 250k records in the csv.

Thanks

Comment: This belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: Add `SHOW WARNINGS\G` and see if it's encountering any weirdness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the line endings of the .txt file?

Comment: Doh! `\r\n`. File came from a Windows System.  Worked without the enclosing characters.